# Does Peano's axioms axiomize true arithmetic?

Tags: logic, model-theory, incompleteness

Let $\mathcal{M}_A=\langle\mathbb N, 0^{\mathcal{M}_A}, s^{\mathcal{M}_A}, +^{\mathcal{M}_A}, \times^{\mathcal{M}_A}, <^{\mathcal{M}_A}\rangle$ be the standard model for the language of arithmetic $\mathcal L_A$. Define theory $\text{Th}(\mathcal{M}_A)=\{\alpha : \mathcal{M}_A\models\alpha\}$.

I have doubts about whether [Peano's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Peano_arithmetic_as_first-order_theory) $\mathsf{PA}$ satisfy $\text{Th}(\mathcal{M}_A)=\{\alpha: \mathsf{PA}\models\alpha\}$. I think the answer is no, according to Godel's first incompleteness theorem. In the linked page, I found the paragraph which confirms my answer:

> According to Gödel's incompleteness theorems, the theory of PA (if consistent) is incomplete. Consequently, there are sentences of first-order logic (FOL) that are true in the standard model of PA but are not a consequence of the FOL axiomatization. Essential incompleteness already arises for theories with weaker axioms, such as Robinson arithmetic.

One thing I don't understand is that how it is possible for the theory of PA to be inconsistent? There are different sets of Peano's axioms whose theory is inconsistent?

What are examples of sentences $\alpha\in\text{Th}(\mathcal{M}_A)$ that satisfies $\mathsf{PA}\not\models\alpha$?

Comment: $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent if it proves a contradiction, in which case it proves everything and hence is complete. Assuming that's not the case, an example of a sentence of the sort you want is a Gödel sentence which (informally) says "I am not provable in $\mathsf{PA}$".

Comment: Not being first-order, I don't know if this will help, but in any Dedekind-infinite set $X$, there exists a subset $M\subset X$ and a function $S: M \to M$ and $x_0\in  M$ such that $(M, S, x_0)$ is a Peano structure (if that the correct term). We would have induction holding:$~\forall P\subset M: [[x_0 \in P~\land ~\forall x\in P: S(x) \in P]\implies P=X]$. Also, any pair of Peano structures are essentially the same structures (order-isomorhpic?) only the names used will differ. This should reassure us that Peano and Dedekind got it right about the set of natural numbers.

Comment: ... Surely, at least the usual 5 axioms will hold. And no additional axioms would be required.

Comment: ... From my work, the only axioms of set theory required for proofs of the above claims are: (1) Subsets, (2) Cartesian Products, and (3) Powersets. The Axiom of Choice is not required.